# Python xlwings excel length of table

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm working on automating some of my work in Excel. A big part of what I'm trying to do is compare some data to determine if it needs to be added into some kind of system or not.

The point where I'm struggling currently is looking up the length of the row in an Excel sheet. The data that is supplied via that Excel sheet may very strongly in length and I think it's sloppy coding if I would let Python just grab all and everything in it.

I have looked around a bit and found some suggestions to use the `Range().vertical`, but it does not seem to be in xlwings anymore.

A workaround I found was reading the compleet sheet, looping it until I found a cell containint "None", then stopping the loop, but this still feels much "non-python-ish).

eg. for the data i'm using

```
    A     B
    1 data1  stuff9
    2 data9  stuff4
    3 data3  stuff3
    4 data4  stuff2
    5
```

What I'm trying to find out is how many rows with data does column A have. In this example I should find 4 (as elegant as possible)

Using the method current_region and size, current_Region gives me back "1", size gives me back "1048576"(i think the max of excel, so it just keeps counting ;)) and the same goes for the end-method.

Comment: what about [current_region](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.current_region) method? Combined with `end` method?

Comment: ah man, I think I missed the one thing in the whole documentation that I actually was searching for (really broke my head over this for like 4 hours >.<). Gonna give it a spin

Comment: @DavidZemens no cigar on the suggested methodes

Comment: It would behoove you to show your efforts (code) as well as elaborate on what "no cigar/didn't work" means (was it an error, if so, include the stack trace. Or did your results diverge from your expectations?If so, describe how, etc.). As a new user here, you were undoubtedly bombarded with reminders to review things like [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and it's an expectation that questions should generally adhere to those (pretty basic) guidelines :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed xlwings and spent 5 minutes looking at the docs, and come up with two options for you:

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.apps[0]
book = app.books[0]
sheet = book.sheets[0]
rng = sheet.range('A1')

# This gives the last row in the TABLE'S current_region
# This will take additional columns in to consideration
rng.current_region.end('down').row

# This gives the last row in column A
rng.end('down').row
```

Based on your example data, both methods yield the result of `4`, but you should note the differences, for example if column B has more data in it, then the first method is not suitable for identifying the "last row" in column A, it will always return the last row of the entire `current_region` object.